# How to get datastore entity urlsafe from dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there anyway to get datastore entity legacy urlsafe in dataflow?

I've tried some method but all failed...

1. Direct encode

   ```
   base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key.SerializeToString()).strip(b'=')
   ```

   => not the same compared with appengine
2. import google.cloud.datastore.key

   => seems conflict with dataflow datastoreio?
3. Copy _app_engine_key_pb2.py from google.cloud.datastore and use it just like to_legacy_urlsafe() source code

   ```
   elements = []
   for part in key.path:
       element_kwargs = {'type': part.kind}
       if part.id:
           element_kwargs['id'] = part.id
       elif part.name:
           element_kwargs['name'] = part.name
       element = _app_engine_key_pb2.Path.Element(**element_kwargs)
       elements.append(element)
   legacy_path = _app_engine_key_pb2.Path(element=elements)
   reference = _app_engine_key_pb2.Reference(
       app=key.partition_id.project_id,
       path=legacy_path,
       name_space=key.partition_id.namespace_id
   )
   raw_bytes = reference.SerializeToString()
   urlsafe = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(raw_bytes).strip(b'=')
   ```

   => still not the same compared with appengine...

Answer (score 0):

The ndb code has:

```
urlsafe = base64.b64encode(self.reference().Encode())
return urlsafe.rstrip('=').replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_')
```

So you should get the same results with:

```
urlsafe = base64.b64encode(key.SerializeToString())
return urlsafe.rstrip('=').replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_')
```

Are you using ndb or the db library?  The to_legacy_urlsafe() function you found seems to match the db library.

Comment: I use ndb, your method seems like my method 1 with more replace rule.
But the urlsafe I get is very different like 'ahooxxooxx' vs 'Cwxyzxyzxyz'...